# How to fix babel Unexpected reserved word 'interface' error

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I want to transpile pure js code in gulp using babel. But there is a variable "interface" in my code. For example

```
function func(interface) {
    console.log(interface)
}
```

How can I fix this?

Packages versions

```
"@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
"gulp": "^4.0.2",
"gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
```

My gulp task

```
function transpileJs() {
    return gulp.src(['folder/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(babel({
             presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('folder/dest/'));
}
```

Error
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Interface is a [reserved word](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) in JavaScript. You cannot use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "interface" is a reserved in "strict mode". That's why you cannot use it as an identifier to declare any variable or function parameter.

Rename you function parameter and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 have an implicit "**strict mode**" so, you'll always get `"use strict";` prepended to your program once running your code through babel.

And now "interface" is a [reserved keyword as of ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) and if you use any reserved keyword as a parameter or variable name, it will throw an error.